# bash shell generates a link that was not specified

Tags: bash

I wrote a simple bash script (in `/homedir`) to run an executable and then move the outputs to `/workdir`. I also made a soft link of `/workdir` named work to `/homedir` for me to switch easily between folders.

All steps are working well, except that an unspecified soft link named 'grids' is created in `/workdir` to itself. I can't delete it otherwise all outputs are gone as well.

How can this happen?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ..
expname=`basename "$PWD"`
echo 'experiment name: '$expname
homedir=/home/b/b380963/icon_foehn/$expname/grids/
workdir=/work/bb1096/b380963/icon_foehn/$expname/grids/

if [ ! -d ${workdir} ]; then
  mkdir -p ${workdir}
fi
cd $homedir
ln -s ${workdir} work

cd /home/b/b380963/nwp/dwd_icon_tools_v2/icontools/
./icongridgen --nml $homedir/gridgen_MCH_july.nml
mv ICON_1E_* $workdir/
mv base_grid* $workdir/
```

Comment: The whole point of `mkdir -p` is to avoid the need to check if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to see in your code:

```
workdir=/work/bb1096/b380963/icon_foehn/$expname/grids/
...
ln -s ${workdir} work
```

The command `ln -s` is the command, creating the symlink.

If you don't like the creation of that symlink, you might put that line in comment (don't delete it: in case you're not satisfied, it's easier to uncomment it).

You can solve your issue, using this command:

```
ln -sTf ...
```

This removes the existing destination files beforehand.

Comment: This line is to link $workdir to $homedir with the name 'work', which is what I want. But the problem is another link of $workdir named 'grids' is created in $workdir itself. That's what confuses me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure, because ln can only create one link at a time. Maybe it's some crap left over from before. However ln works like cp does in that if the last argument is a directory, then it creates a link in that directory with the name of the last component in the first argument. Maybe that helps you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the left over from multiple times of execution. I solved it by using ln -sTf, which remove the existing destination files beforehand.

Comment: @YueTian: thanks for your reply, I've modified my answer, adding the final solution, for reference purposes.